# User Login Form Outside the Default wp-login Form

Tags: login

I'm trying to implement a custom registration process consisted of 4 steps.
At the first step user enters her credentials and pushes "continue" to proceed to the next step and the form is sent to the same page.

Here I successfully insert a new user to WP database and I want this user to be logged in right after this. I do it like this:

```
if ( isset($_POST["user-email"]) && isset($_POST["user-password"]) ) :

// Getting data from the Form
$user_login = esc_attr($_POST["user-email"]);
$user_password = esc_attr($_POST["user-password"]);
$user_email = esc_attr($_POST["user-email"]);

// Composing an array with user credentials data
$user_data =
    array(
        'user_login'    =>  $user_login,
        'user_pass'     =>  $user_password,
        'user_email'    =>  $user_email,
        'role'          =>  'student'
    );

// Inserting new user to the db
wp_insert_user( $user_data );

// Trying to log in
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $user_login;
$creds['user_password'] = $user_password;
$creds['remember'] = true;

// As far as I know whis does the trick
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) echo $user->get_error_message();

endif;
```

The problem starts from here. **wp_signon** for some reason does not login user, which I check by the following:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : echo "Yuppiee!";
else : echo "FAIL!";
```

And I get "FAIL" all the time. Then I dug up the Internets and tried the following:

```
wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : echo "Yuppiee!";
else : echo "FAIL!";
```

And I have my "Yuppiee!" finally, but not for long. After page is reloaded I FAIL! again.

At the end I've got a new user added in my WP database and I can see her in the *wp-admin/users* panel and I can login this user through default *wp-login* form and I've got Yuppiee! all the way. But when I try to login the same user programmatically I got FAIL on page reload.

Can you help me to get through this? Please?!

Comment: After you call the `wp_signon()` function, are you redirecting the user, or does your script continue to run eventually calling `is_user_logged_in()` ?

Comment: @Chris I do not redirect user to anywhere. Please consider these parts of code as a one piece. The algorithm on this SINGLE page is the following: 1. I read POST data >> 2. I insert a new user >> 3. I try to log her in >> 4. I do the check `is_user_logged_in()` >> 5. I do stuff.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the issue, using your code. I'm hoping you've tried this while deactivating all other plugins and you've checked your theme, if any login filters are being used.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a Wordpress bug. According to the documentation, `wp_signon()` is the correct function to log a user in.

In your script, you are using `is_user_logged_in()` to verify the user was correctly logged in after your call to `wp_signon()`. is_user_logged_in() uses the `global $current_user` variable which doesn't appear to get set when using `wp_signon()`.

`wp_set_current_user()` sets the `global $current_user`, but does not create the auth cookie needed to keep the user logged in.

Try the following:

```
$user = wp_signon();
wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
is_user_logged_in();
```

This way, you are logging the user in (creating the auth cookie) and setting the current user before attempting to verify using `is_user_logged_in()`.

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I've been doing: first `wp_signon()` -> `wp_set_current_user()` -> then I check if `is_user_logged_in()` and I can't get user logged in this way.