# Proper way to pass credentials in a custom login form to avoid "headers already sent"

Tags: plugin-development, login, errors, headers

I'm working on a custom login page plugin. I'm trying to figure out how to log the user in without creating "headers already sent" errors.

I was calling `wp_signon` directly after the user clicked "login," but quickly found that this approach yields "headers already sent" errors. I've switched to using hooks:

```
private function attemptLogin() {
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( $this->Cms, 'authenticateUser' ), 10, 2 );
    do_action( 'after_setup_theme', $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'] );
}
```

But, as you've probably guessed, this yields the same errors since I'm still, in essence, executing the login immediately.

How can I leave the hook to run on its own schedule to avoid errors, while still making the user's credentials available to it?

I've searched both Google and this site for the answer to no avail. The closest to an answer I've found is [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114714/user-login-form-outside-the-default-wp-login-form), but I'm still unsure how to implement the advice while still passing the user's credentials.

Comment: Why are you running it on `'after_setup_theme'`?

Comment: @Ervald: I was doing so because [that's what's recommended in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon#Examples). Should I be using a different hook?

Comment: [Here's another tutorial I found that almost answers my question](http://www.codehooks.com/how-to-login-a-user-with-a-wordpress-plugin/); but, again, he's not having to worry about passing the credentials. He's generating the credentials after the redirect.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial that seems to be doing it the same way I was originally.](http://www.tutorialstag.com/custom-wordpress-login-without-using-a-plugin.html) What was I doing wrong?

Comment: [And this one.](http://www.sutanaryan.com/wordpress-custom-login-page-without-using-a-plugin-the-right-way/) Perhaps my problem is not that I wasn't using a hook previously?

Comment: [From what it says here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335833/wordpress-wp-signon-function-not-working), it might be helpful to know that I'm implementing this custom login form as a shortcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon successful login `wp_signon()` sets a cookie in the http response header. Hence it has to be called before any HTML output is sent to the browser. Otherwise the "headers already sent" error will occur.

After a successfull login you should redirect your user. Otherwise the login information will not present when the page HTML is rendered.

A very sketchy but working code:

```
// process login requests each time wordpress renders a page. 
function my_custom_login_process() {
    // check if login credentials are present in the current http request
    if ( isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) && isset( $_POST['user_password'] ) ) {
        // try login
        $user = wp_signon( $_POST );

        if ( is_wp_error($user) ) // didn't work. Tell the user.
            exit('Nope...');
        else // worked! Get him somewhere.
            wp_redirect( get_bloginfo('url') );
    }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','my_custom_login_process');
```

Additionally you should protect your login form with a nonce, and add a nonce verification to the function above. The easiest way to do this is by using [`wp_nonce_field()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field) in the login form.

### Nonces explained

[EDIT]: A [Nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) is a unique token, that gets registered along with a form.  It is mainly used to make sure that a form has been generated by the Webserver, before any data is accepted for further processing. All forms in the admin area are using nonces (or at least should do).

During the login process it will provide basic protection against brute force attacks. (This means flooding your WordPress with blank POST requests containing arbitrary username / password combinations.)

---

(BTW: It seems like you have a little misconception on hooks. You really should not register (`do_action()`) and call a hook (`do_action()`) with arbitrary function arguments. Other plugins might also have registered their functions. [This article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/07/definitive-guide-wordpress-hooks/) looks like a pretty good starting point for a deeper understanding.)

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation! I'm going to try this ASAP.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why a nonce is needed?

Comment: I've successfully implemented your approach. It does seem odd, doesn't that WordPress wouldn't automatically throttle wp_signon attempts and perhaps include a lockout after x failed attempts? Anyway, thanks again for the great answer!

Comment: Thx :) As far as I can see in the source WP doesn't even count failed login attempts. Anyway there are some plugins out there, dealing with brute force attacks and other security issues. e.g. that one: http://wordpress.org/plugins/login-lockdown/

Comment: Hmm, seems like a bit of an oversight to me. Yes, I believe I have the iThemes Security plugin set to do just that. I'll definitely work on getting my login form using nonces, too.